# Distribution of X³/Y where X and Y are uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are two uniformly distributed variables in interval $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ respectively (a>0 and c>0).

What is the distribution of the variable $Z$ defined as $Z=X^3/Y$?

Comment: Hint: Write the event $Z \le z$ as $X^3 \le zY$.  The integrals are now straightforward (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent).

Comment: What is the first thing you've tried to answer the question yourself?

Comment: The difficulty encountered is finding the change of variable for Y so as to have a Jacobian equal to w. This will help to simply the expression of the marginal for Z.

Comment: Looks messy and complicated to me